# How can one modify for loop in QTP?

Tags: for-loop, vbscript, qtp

I was asked this question in an interview, here it goes

'You have written for loop from 1 to 100, but I want to run the for loop from 70 to 100, ignoring previous iteration from 1 to 69. You are not allowed to change anything in the script, how can you automate this in QTP?'

Can somebody please tell me how I can achieve this?

Comment: I was going to say - it really depends on HOW the loop is written, and at what level the iteration mechanics are happening.  (in a user defined func?  in an action?  using a datasheet with 100 rows?, etc..  Then I read Amit's Answer below, and that looks quite feasable to me, so I'd go with that.

Answer (score 1):

Please follow the below steps and you will be able to work with [for loop](http://qtp-interviewquestions.blogspot.in/2016/08/what-is-difference-between-for-loop-and.html) :

```
Step 1. Put a break point where the loop starts.
Step 2. Run the Script and when it stops at break point, go to view-->debug-->Console and change the value of your iterator variable from 0(start value) to 70.
```

example : i = 70
    Step 3. Run the script and you will achieve your target.

Answer (score 0):

You could always check the value of your iteration variable as the first step in your '***For***' loop and if the value is ***1***, change it to ***70***